# Least amount of intervals covering array of numbers

Tags: algorithms

Lets have Array of numbers eg. $A=[29, 1, 26, 4, 28, 35, 17, 42, 51]$.

I want to find least number of intervals of maximal length $10$, which covers all numbers. eg. intervals $= (1,10), (17,26), (28,37),(42,51)$

solution 1:

> Find smallest element of $A= \min(A)$. First interval will be $(\min(A),\min(A)+10)$, 
>   Remove elements from $A$, which belongs to this interval and repeat until $A$ is empty. For example $I(1) = (1,10)$, $A =[29,26,28,35,17,42,51] ..., I(2) = (17,26) ...$

solution 2:

> Find interval which covers most elements from $A$. 
>   Remove them from $A$ and repeat until $A$ is empty.
>   For example $I(1) = (28,37)$, $A =[1,26,4,17,42,51]$. $I(2)=(1,10) ... , I(3)=(17,26) ..., I(4)=(42,51)$.

Are these solutions correct algorithms and are they correctly solving my problem of redistribution or are they wrong ?

Comment: A counterexample to the second algorithm is $\{1, 5, 6,13,14, 20\}$.

Comment: Sick, that I didnt catched that, thank you Henning.